# arm assembly Invalid number of vectors

Tags: assembly, arm, inline-assembly, armv8

There were two questions about asm assembly in armv8.

First,"Invalid number of vectors," my code is below.

```
"prfm   pldl1keep, [%7, #64] \n"
"ld1    {v0.4s, v1.4s, v2.4s, v3.4s, v4.4s, v5.4s}, [%7], #48 \n"
```

[image]

Second,"Mismatched register size suffix".

```
"prfm   pldl1keep, [%5, #64] \n"
"ld1    {v0.4s, v1.2s}, [%7], #24 \n"
```

[image]
I directly google these two questions, but got few answers.

Comment: What exactly are you hoping those instructions will do?  Are you asking why they're invalid, or how to accomplish what you want with multiple instructions?  Also, that looks like inline asm.  What constraint did `%7` come from, in case that matters?  And what is the final asm instruction after the compiler filled in the `%7` in the asm template, which the assembler then choked on?

Comment: Am I reading the [docs](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0802b/LD1_advsimd_sngl_vector.html) right?  It looks like ld1 only supports up to 4 registers.  As for mismatched register size, are you sure you can mix and match sizes like that in a single instruction?  The docs indicate that the 2 register variant can only use either #16 or #32.

Comment: Thx, all of you. You are right. I divide the first ld1 instruction into two ld1, then, it works. And the second question, I also divide the ld1 into two ld1(#16 and #8), then, it work.

Comment: Kindly do not post pictures of code.  Always post your code as text so others can compile / assemble it and reproduce your error.

Comment: Good idea, but I don't think it's proper way to this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Turning my comment (which appears to have answered the question) into an 'answer' so this question can get closed out.*

According to the [docs](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0802b/LD1_advsimd_sngl_vector.html), `ld1` only supports up to 4 registers and you are specifying 6, which would be an `invalid number of vectors`.

As for `mismatched register size suffix`, the docs indicate that the 2 register variant can only use either #16 or #32, not the #24 you have provided.  Perhaps mismatched sizes is not supported?

Note that I'm not knowledgeable enough about ARM to comment on the efficiency of OP's solution.  There might be other solutions that work better.  However, this appears to explain the cause of the two error messages.